# R: Best way to mimic a dictionary with "non-string" keys

Tags: r, dictionary

I've seen some ways to mimic a dictionary in R using the function `names`. But names/keys have to be strings...

What I want is an efficient way to use keys of any kind:

Let's say I have the following dictionary structure

```
dico = list(list(dep=list(11, 22), candidates=list(list(grp.id=15, sim.score=0.8))))
dico[[2]] <- list(dep=list(33, 44), candidates=list(list(grp.id=155, sim.score=0.88)))
```

What would be the best way to retrieve the entry from the dictionary where key is `list(33, 44)`?

The operator to compare keys would be `identical()`, but I can't figure out how to formulate the request, but doing something like (finds the id using `which`):

```
key = list(33, 44)
which(sapply(dico, function(x) { identical(x$dep, key) } ))
```

Maybe, the data structure should also be something else, in the first place?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT:** Richie's data.framed approach would do the job if I do as follows:

```
the_data <- data.frame(
  dep1        = c(11, 33),
  dep2        = c(22, 44),
  candidates  = c( list(list(grp.id=15, sim.score=0.8)), list(list(grp.id=155, sim.score=0.88)) )
)
```

Since, I need the list of candidates (couple `[grp.id, sim.score]`) for each key to be extendable. That is: **1 -> N relationship** between a dep and its related candidates...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are overcomplicating things with your data structure.  If each list item (a person?) has four values associated with them, store the data in a data frame.

```
the_data <- data.frame(
  dep1                = c(11, 33),
  dep2                = c(22, 44),
  candidate.grp.id    = c(15, 155),
  candidate.sim.score = c(0.8, 0.88)
)
```

Then you can use `subset`, or standard indexing to retrieve what you want.

```
subset(the_data, dep1 == 33 & dep2 == 44)
```

---

From your comments, I half suspect (it isn't very clear) that several candidates can have the same `dep` values.  In this case, just repeat the `dep` values in the data frame.

So this complicated data structure:

```
dico <- list(
  list(
    dep        = list(11, 22), 
    candidates = list(
      list(
        grp.id    = 15, 
        sim.score = 0.8
      )
    )
  ),
  list(
    dep        = list(33, 44), 
    candidates = list(
      list(
        grp.id    = 155, 
        sim.score = 0.88
      )
    )
  ),
  list(
    dep        = list(33, 44), 
    candidates = list(
      list(
        grp.id    = 99, 
        sim.score = 0.99
      )
    )
  )
)
```

simplifies to:

```
the_data <- data.frame(
  dep1                = c(11, 33, 33),
  dep2                = c(22, 44, 44),
  candidate.grp.id    = c(15, 155, 99),
  candidate.sim.score = c(0.8, 0.88, 0.99)
)
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. Sorry for that, but I made a mistake while simplifying my sample code. The real structure needs candidates to be a dynamic list of candidates. This can't be 4 values as the structure I need looks like this: `dico = list(list(dep=list(11, 22), candidates=list(list(grp.id=15, sim.score=0.8))))` (I edited the code in my questions body).

Comment: But, practically, your answer is still applicable: I could use a dataframe with 2 columns where `dep` (the key) would be a unique 2-integers vector, and `candidates` (the value), a list of couples (int, double)... This way should work.
Do you have an idea of the perfs while subsetting a df VS using which like I do? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "dynamic list", but I still think your data structure is too complicated.  Edit your question to provide sample data that won't fit in a data frame, if you think that I've oversimplified.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify myself. Just saying that your approach is fine as long as I can store lists in dataframes... Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, you can't store lists in data frames, but my point is that you don't need to.  All you need is a regular data frame with four columns.

Comment: If there are 10 candidates belonging to a dep key, then simply repeat the dep key in 10 rows, one for each cnadiade

Comment: Ok, got it now. I'm a bit slow today. I was stuck in my head with the dictionary approach (and unique keys...). Now subsetting to get the rows related to a specified dep makes absolutely sens to me. Thanks for your time.